# Sometimes main BPEL process doesn't receive a callback message from asyncronous process

Tags: asynchronous, callback, wso2, bpel, apache-ode

Sometimes main BPEL process doesn't receive a callback message from asyncronous process.
Asyncronous process invokes the callback and completes successfully, but the main process stays in active status waiting for receive incoming activity.

Main process continues to execute after **manual** request to callback endpoint (request contains same content as in asynchronous process's output variable).
Usually same callback work successfully.